# Using Data from Array

Tags: java, arrays

I am making small java game, and I am trying to set enemies x coordinate through array of coordinates.

```
public Enemy() 
{
    int[] xcoordinate = new int[]{40,60,80,100,120,140,160,180,200,220,240,260}; 
    for(int i = 0;i <= xcoordinate.length;i++){
      addObject(new enemy(5,5),*sets enemy's x coordinate to a number from an array*,180);   
    }
}
```

Basically what I am trying to do, is to automatically add 12 enemies, and their x coordinates will be taken from an array, but I am not sure how to do it. So enemy number 5, will have an x coordinate of 120. Any help will be useful. Thank you

Comment: `xcoordinate[i]`?

Comment: Do not forget to adjust your FOR. 'xcoordinate.length' to 'xcoordinate.length-1'. The exception will appear.

Comment: you can pass xcoodrinate[i] as constructor argument to Enemy constructor, and save x coordinate as a field of Enemy, e.g.

Comment: Please consider studying any tutorial on Java arrays. Voting to close question as it will not likely help future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

You use a counter in your loop.
To access an array at position x, just use xcoordinate[x].